# please help with fixing my dpkg issue 30 packages are broken

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, apport

due to a stupidity, I accidentally deleted my dpkg folder.. and tried to restore it in all possible ways. but still following packages are broken.. can anyone please help

```
dpkg: error processing package xserver-xorg-video-vmware-hwe-16.04 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 util-linux
 procps
 udev
 apache2
 cups-daemon
 grub-common
 grub2-common
 grub-pc-bin
 grub-pc
 uuid-runtime
 keyboard-configuration
 initramfs-tools-core
 initramfs-tools
 console-setup-linux
 console-setup
 ifupdown
 apport
 apport-gtk
 cups-core-drivers
 cups
 tomcat7
 xserver-xorg-core-hwe-16.04
 xserver-xorg-input-evdev-hwe-16.04
 xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-hwe-16.04
 xserver-xorg-input-wacom-hwe-16.04
 xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu-hwe-16.04
 xserver-xorg-video-radeon-hwe-16.04
 xserver-xorg-video-ati-hwe-16.04
 xserver-xorg-video-fbdev-hwe-16.04
 xserver-xorg-video-intel-hwe-16.04
 xserver-xorg-video-nouveau-hwe-16.04
 xserver-xorg-video-qxl-hwe-16.04
 xserver-xorg-video-vesa-hwe-16.04
 xserver-xorg-video-vmware-hwe-16.04
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Did you try `apt install -f` and `dpkg --configure -a`?

Comment: yes sir I did, but to no avail...